# WMI Quota violation error while waiting for event

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm making an implementation of a `WmiFileSystemWatcher` (no need to explain why the regular `FileSystemWatcher` is a total crap).
It works great for my needs (bit slow but reliable), but after a few runs I start getting "Quota Violation" when starting the `ManagementEventWatcher`.

This is my Wql:

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE
Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' AND
TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 
'Win32_Directory.Name="D:\\\\temp"'
```

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Sounds like a classic XY question.  You can avoid the quota violation exception by cleaning up that directory and getting rid of the junk files.  After which it won't be slow anymore and your program crashes again with IOExceptions like it did before.  Now you got two problems.

Comment: @Nissim Were you able to find a solution for this? I am currently experiencing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you close your program, or no longer need the watcher object, you need to explicitly call the [Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.stop.aspx) method and then [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w.aspx). If your `Stop` call is asynchronous then call `Dispose` in the callback event.